# tuleap and agiledashboard plugin

Tags: linux

after I've installed and enabled agiledashboard plugin, I'm not able to access web home of Tuleap anymore. 
I found the following kind of error in httpd log:

```
[Mon Aug 31 10:48:10 2015] [error] [client 10.1.3.200] PHP Fatal error:  Undefined class constant 'SERVICES_ALLOWED_FOR_PROJECT' in /usr/share/tuleap/plugins/agiledashboard/include/agiledashboardPlugin.class.php on line 72
```

But I don't know how to solve the issue.
What could be the cause of this issue?
Is it possible to manually disable the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed a newer version of AgileDashboard that depends on new features in Core. Hence you should update tuleap packages:

```
yum update tuleap\*
```